# Oracle timeout setting: 'CONNECT_TIME'

Tags: oracle, timeout, profile

I am trying to test a timeout setting in my local Oracle instance by setting the CONNECT_TIME to 1 minute like the following :

```
  ALTER PROFILE TEST LIMIT CONNECT_TIME 1;
```

Then I also set the RESOURCE_LIMIT parameter in INIT.ORA like the following:

```
  RESOURCE_LIMIT = true
```

I restarted Oracle DB and then I connected via SQL Developer to a user with the TEST profile, I executed a query and then waited for like 3 minutes to then try to re-execute that query, what I was expecting was to receive some sort of timeout error. Can you anyone tell me if there other settings that I need to do before it'd work.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried from SQL plus?  Maybe sqldeveloper is doing some ping or other communications in the background?

Comment: @OldProgrammer Thanks for the response.  It turned out that I had to set the RESOURCE_LIMIT like this `alter system set resource_limit = true` and then it worked. I was wondering if there other ways to timeout/disconnect a session of user that would cause a Closed Connection error ? `SQLNET.EXPIRE_TIME` ?